# How to fix a new textField position after panGesture?

Tags: uipangesturerecognizer

I need some help with a litter issue in my code.
I have a view with two textField one on the top and another on the bottom, both over a imageView.
I applied a Pan Gesture in both textfields to allow change their position after the user load an image.
But when I show a activityView to share the new image, the textFields return the previous location.
I'd like to fix them in the new location after panGesture.
What can I do? Or What am I forgetting to do?

```
   This is my Pan Gesture Action
@IBAction func didPanTfTop(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

    if sender.state == .began {
        print("Gesture began")
        textFieldOriginalCenter = tfTop.center
    } else if sender.state == .changed {
        print("Gesture is changed")
        tfTop.center = CGPoint(x: textFieldOriginalCenter.x + translation.x, y: textFieldOriginalCenter.y + translation.y)
    } else if sender.state == .ended {
        print("Gesture ended")

    }
}
```

And this is my activityView methods...

```
@IBAction func share(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    Feedback.share.hapticFeedback()
    let memeImage = generateMemedImage()
    let activityView = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [memeImage], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityView.completionWithItemsHandler = { (activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?, completed: Bool, returnedItems: [Any]?, error: Error?) -> Void in

        if completed {
            self.save()
            print("Image has saved")
        }
    }
    present(activityView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Could you give me some hint for this? I tried a few options but it was a bit difficult with my current knowledge But I am still trying. :)

Comment: Ok Rob, thank you so much for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this behavior of seeing views snapping back to their original locations is a result of a combination of (a) using auto-layout constraints; and (b) doing something that triggers the constraints to be reapplied. This process of constraints being reapplied can sometimes be triggered by the most innocuous of UI action. Bottom line, rather than worrying about what triggered the constraints from being re-applied, it’s best to just make sure that your views will stay where you want them to, even after this happens.

One solution is to update the [`transform`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) of the views rather than the `center`, e.g.:

```
var originalTransform: CGAffineTransform!

@IBAction func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        originalTransform = gesture.view!.transform

    case .changed, .ended:
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)
        gesture.view?.transform = originalTransform.translatedBy(x: translation.x, y: translation.y)

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

This technique works, but also feels a bit fragile, dependent upon poorly documented behavior between constraints and view transforms.

Another, more robust, but a little more complicated, approach is to adjust the constraints’ `constant` property. For example, you can create `@IBOutlet` references for the constraints, themselves, hook up those outlets in IB, and then you gesture recognizer can update their `constant` properties accordingly:

```
@IBOutlet weak var horizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var verticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

private var originalHorizontalConstant: CGFloat!
private var originalVerticalConstant: CGFloat!

@IBAction func handlePan(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch gesture.state {
    case .began:
        originalHorizontalConstant = horizontalConstraint.constant
        originalVerticalConstant = verticalConstraint.constant

    case .changed, .ended:
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)
        horizontalConstraint.constant = originalHorizontalConstant + translation.x
        verticalConstraint.constant = originalVerticalConstant + translation.y

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Now, clearly if you’re potentially dragging different views around this can get a little messier, but hopefully the above illustrates the basic idea.

Whichever technique you apply, the basic notion is to avoid updating `center` or `frame` of a view whose position is dictated by auto-layout constraints.

Comment: The first solution worked well to me, but I got a question about the second one.


Each TextField in my code has three constraints (top or bottom, right and left). I believe that to implement the @IBOutlets horizontalConstraint and verticalConstraint as you suggest, I have to remove the originals constraints, keeping only these two new constraints. Am I right?

Comment: No, you always want to update the `constant` (Apple discourages from adding and removing constraints) if those were your constraints, you’d alter right and left constraints’ constants with `translation.x` and top and bottom constraints’ constants with `translation.y`. In my example, I had top, height, left, and width, so I only had to adjust top and left to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Awesome Rob. I understood everything you suggested now. I used the two options and everything worked well. Thank you so much!!!