# How to crop an image with a selectable area in swift 4 or later?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, swift4

I need some help with a function that I'd like to implement in my app.
I have a view with an image view with content mode in Aspect Fit. When I get an image from my library I would like to crop an area with an adjustable rectangle creating a new image.
I've looked for some exemple or online tutorial but I did not succeed.
Can anyone help me with that?
Here are the images from my View.

[image: This is my view in the Storyboard].

[image: And here is my view in Simulator]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simple solution is to just render the image view within a particular `CGRect`:

```
func snapshot(in imageView: UIImageView, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect).image { _ in
        imageView.drawHierarchy(in: imageView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
}
```

The limitation of that approach is that if the image is a considerably higher resolution than the image view could render (as is often the case when we use “aspect scale fit”), you’ll lose this additional precision.

If you want to preserve the resolution, you should convert the `CGRect` to coordinates with the image, in this case, assuming “aspect scale fit” (namely, centered and scaled so the whole image is shown):

```
func snapshot(in imageView: UIImageView, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
    assert(imageView.contentMode == .scaleAspectFit)

    let image = imageView.image!

    // figure out what the scale is

    let imageRatio = imageView.bounds.width / imageView.bounds.height
    let imageViewRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height

    let scale: CGFloat
    if imageRatio > imageViewRatio {
        scale = image.size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    } else {
        scale = image.size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    }

    // convert the `rect` into coordinates within the image, itself

    let size = rect.size * scale
    let origin = CGPoint(x: image.size.width  / 2 - (imageView.bounds.midX - rect.minX) * scale,
                         y: image.size.height / 2 - (imageView.bounds.midY - rect.minY) * scale)
    let scaledRect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

    // now render the image and grab the appropriate rectangle within
    // the image’s coordinate system

    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
    format.scale = image.scale
    format.opaque = false

    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: scaledRect, format: format).image { _ in
        image.draw(at: .zero)
    }
}
```

Using this extension:

```
extension CGSize {
    static func * (lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: lhs.width * rhs, height: lhs.height * rhs)
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your tip. But I have a question about the property size syntax. Is it correct to use operands between types CGSize and CGFloat? (let size = rect.size * scale) The Xcode does not accept and show this message "Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGSize' and 'CGFloat"
'

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to include an extension that I use all the time for multiplying a`CGSize` times a scalar `CGFloat`. I’ve included it in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Rob, you helped me a lot. If it is not too much bother, I wonder if you could count on your help in another problem. If you have time, follow the link:   https://stackoverflow.com/q/54163818/10148333

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly there are two parts to your question:

1. An adjustable rectangle area over the image
2. Crop an `UIImage`

Break your google query and search for solution based on the above questions separately.

Or probably take help or use something like this:

[iOS-Image-Crop-View](https://github.com/myang-git/iOS-Image-Crop-View)

Comment: Hi, I think this is exactly what I want to do, I will try to implement, since the code is very old. If I can, I'll let you know.