# How to select an area in a view just touching and dragging in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, touchesbegan

I need to implement a functionality in my app that allow the user to select an area in an `imageView` just touching and dragging.

I tried with `touchesBegan`, but as I am new in Swift I had some difficulty.

How can I do that?

I got here, but what now?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touch = touches.first
    lastPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)

    for touch in touches {
        print(touch.location(in: imageView))
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    touch = touches.first
    currentPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)

    self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()

    lastPoint = currentPoint
}
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Can you post the code showing what you’ve done so far and describe what’s not working about it?

Comment: Hi Aaron, I'm still at the beginning, but follow the code.

Comment: That’s my problem, Rob. I am stuck. I don’t know how can I finish my code so as to have at the end a selected area.

Comment: You sad I did a great first step. But I don’t know what I have to do now. Can you give some hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do something when you’re done selecting the portion of the image, e.g., implement [`touchesEnded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended).

Let’s imagine, for example, that you want to show a rectangle of the prospective area as you drag and you want to make an image snapshot of the selected portion when you’re done dragging. You could then do something like:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var startPoint: CGPoint?

let rectShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = {
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
    return shapeLayer
}()

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    startPoint = nil

    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    startPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)

    // you might want to initialize whatever you need to begin showing selected rectangle below, e.g.

    rectShapeLayer.path = nil

    imageView.layer.addSublayer(rectShapeLayer)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first, let startPoint = startPoint else { return }

    let currentPoint: CGPoint

    if let predicted = event?.predictedTouches(for: touch), let lastPoint = predicted.last {
        currentPoint = lastPoint.location(in: imageView)
    } else {
        currentPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)
    }

    let frame = rect(from: startPoint, to: currentPoint)

    // you might do something with `frame`, e.g. show bounding box

    rectShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(rect: frame).cgPath
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first, let startPoint = startPoint else { return }

    let currentPoint = touch.location(in: imageView)
    let frame = rect(from: startPoint, to: currentPoint)

    // you might do something with `frame`, e.g. remove bounding box but take snapshot of selected `CGRect`

    rectShapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
    let image = imageView.snapshot(rect: frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // do something with this `image`
}

private func rect(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: min(from.x, to.x),
           y: min(from.y, to.y),
           width: abs(to.x - from.x),
           height: abs(to.y - from.y))
}
```

Where you have this `UIView` extension for creating a snapshot image:

```swift
extension UIView {

    /// Create image snapshot of view.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - rect: The coordinates (in the view's own coordinate space) to be captured. If omitted, the entire `bounds` will be captured.
    ///   - afterScreenUpdates: A Boolean value that indicates whether the snapshot should be rendered after recent changes have been incorporated. Specify the value false if you want to render a snapshot in the view hierarchy’s current state, which might not include recent changes.
    /// - Returns: The `UIImage` snapshot.

    func snapshot(rect: CGRect? = nil, afterScreenUpdates: Bool = true) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect ?? bounds).image { _ in
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: afterScreenUpdates)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to do something other than capturing snapshot of the image, then, fine, do whatever you want. But this illustrates the basic idea.

---

A couple of minor things in my above example:

- Note that I limit my ivars to those things I absolutely need. E.g. the current `touch` should probably be a local variable, not an ivar. We should always limit our variables to the narrowest possible scope to avoid unintended consequences, etc.
- I added a minor refinement to your `touchesMoved` to use predictive touches. That’s not necessary, but can help minimize any perceived lagginess when dragging one’s finger.
- I’m not at all sure why you called `setNeedsDisplay`. It seems unnecessary unless there was something else that you were intending there.
- I’m not sure what content mode you were using for your image view. For example, if you were using “Aspect scale fit” and wanted to do a snapshot of that, you might chose a different snapshotting algorithm, for example as outlined in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54191120/1271826.

Comment: Super cool Rob. You're amazing. That is exactly what I need. Your explanation helped me to understand many points that I had not imagined. I was abble to finish my test app. Now I will try to implement theses functions in my main app. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I have just one question Rob. If I have a textField above the image, what do I need to do to join them (textField and image) in a new image after the crop? I think I have to change the snapshot function. Am I right?

Comment: I’d suggest that after you’ve captured your snapshot image, that you then create yet another image (using `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` again). I haven’t tested it, but it would be something like https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/e4fa480617a3f63494ab78e36f3b7d7f (tho I just did that with image above text, but you can play around with it to yield whatever you want).